# Missing Network Adapters. Only showing vEthernet

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, local-area-network

We had an older server at one location, and it was online and backing up online fine. And when the local ISP started charging per gig of usage. So we shut it down. Fast forward a year later, we have another location where it could go. So I bring the server there and it won't connect to the internet.

Log into it and see that the only network adapter is vEthernet. (It also has HyperV but not being used.)

[Adapter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1c0r.jpg)

Nothing but vEthernet is showing in Computer Management.

[Computer Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar5MU.jpg)

Tried multiple ports on the back.
Tried static and DHCP address.

A really long time ago our local ISP had a box get struck by lightning. But at the time the server was off, but still plugged in. Could that have still screwed something up? Just trying to rule everything out.

Thanks

[Network plug1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYdze.png)
[Network plug2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H91mM.png)

Comment: Does the motherboard have onboard network ports? Or are they daughter boards?

Comment: Both. I've tried plugging into both. Same result.

Comment: do the network devices show up in the BIOS?

Comment: I'll have to check that out when I get out there tomorrow. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It does not show up in the bios. I'm looking at getting a replacement network card now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the network card. I replaced it and the network connection resumed to normal.